# Devise not signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've set up Devise other times. But for some reason, this time I cannot signin. I configured my app with http://prelang.com/.

This is my routes:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions", passwords: "users/passwords"}
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

 #->Prelang (user_login:devise/stylized_paths)
  devise_scope :user do
    get    "login"   => "users/sessions#new",         as: :new_user_session
    post   "login"   => "users/sessions#create",      as: :user_session
    delete "signout" => "users/sessions#destroy",     as: :destroy_user_session

    get    "signup"  => "users/registrations#new",    as: :new_user_registration
    post   "signup"  => "users/registrations#create", as: :user_registration
    put    "signup"  => "users/registrations#update", as: :update_user_registration
    get    "account" => "users/registrations#edit",   as: :edit_user_registration
  end
```

And my signin view `sessions/new.html.slim`:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {id: "loginForm"}) do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.input :email, as: :string, label: "Correo electrónico", placeholder: "example@gmail.com", required: true, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", id: "username"
  .form-group
    = f.input :password, label: "Contraseña", placeholder: "*******", required: false, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", id: "password"

  = f.submit "Iniciar sesión", class: "btn btn-success btn-block"
  = link_to "Registrarte", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-block"
```

The user that I'm trying to signin with has been created by signing up. This is how the user's object looks like:

```
#<User id: 3, email: "myemail@gmail.com", 
created_at: "2017-03-01 11:21:47", 
updated_at: "2017-03-01 11:21:47", 
username: nil>
```

What I get is the flash alert `Invalid Login or password.`. If I take a look to the params been passed to `SessionsController` (`new` action) this is how it looks like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"9jQjU5BuFDJJRdJuPZVvHHzz3R3t16H+Jh46O4w3KPU=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"myemail@gmail.com", "password"=>"holahola"},
 "commit"=>"Iniciar sesión",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"users/sessions"}
```

How can I make it work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `params email` and user table `record email` looks different

Comment: @ashvin Thanks for pointing out. The info was wrong. I updated it with the right database record.

Comment: Your form submit as post request ?  asking because is simple form submitting as get.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Preflang uses both email or username to login. Instead of naming sessions/new.hmtl.slim input method for identifying the user as `:email` I had to call it `:login`. Now it works.

The method is described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-or-sign_up).